# Regex expression for ISO 8601 duration

Tags: regex, date, duration, iso8601, period

I've been looking at ISO 8061 Wikipedia - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations

I want to create a regex so that:

Allowed Input

```
P1Y // date component only
P5W
```

Not Allowed Input

```
P1Y5W // No Year, month, week together. Just one of them.
P1Y2DT0H3M // No hour, minute, second
```

I tried

```
/^(-?)P(?=\d|T\d)(?:(\d+)Y)?(?:(\d+)M)?(?:(\d+)([DW]))/
```

`P1Y2DT0H3M` didn't pass while `P1Y2D`(shouldn't pass either)

What should I do?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It is not clear to me what you consider acceptable. You write somewhere "no hour, minute, second", so you don't want a time component, but then why in your regex you mention "T"? Are you looking for `^P\d+[YMDW]$`?

Comment: @trincot I still don't want time component. only duration part should be  accepted.  I originally got this regex from https://rgxdb.com/r/MD2234J and I was playing with it, hoping it will work. I'm not super familiar with regex.

Comment: I don't understand what your requirements are. Like I said, why is there a "T" in your regex when you don't want it? Do you only want exactly one of Y, M, D, W? Then did you check my proposal?

Comment: @trincot Don't worry about my Regex. It's a bad one. On a side note. Y.ou got it right, your solution works. Thank you!

Comment: Do you want to allow durations with a minus sign? Like `-P1Y` or `P-1Y`or `-P0Y` or `P-0Y`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you only want one period specifier that is either Y, M, D or W, you can use this regex:

```
^P\d+[YMDW]$
```